# How to create File field?

Tags: java, file

I have a constructor that will take File as parameter. How do I create a field for the file so that all other methods can access it?

Constructor will look like this:

```
MyClass(File f) throws Exception;
```

The file is gonna look something like this:

```
. . . . .
. . . . .
. x . . .
. x x . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
```

I want to create a method that will get row and column from this file, but to do that, I need a field.

Comment: See [The Java™ Tutorials - Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). Or just read **any** java manual/guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a member to the class and copy the information needed from the File object into it.

You also could simply add a File member to the class, setting the reference in the constructor like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private File file;

    public MyClass(File f) throws Exception {
        this.file = f;
    }
}
```

BTW: As this are Java Basics you should really try to learn the basic things. There are thousands of tutorials for Java online.